# Compose Tweet connect app or authorize web doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit

I followed the guides here. 
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Compose-Tweets

On a physical device if I have twitter app installed, and I trigger an action to compose a tweet, it opens the twitter app, asks to connect with the logged in twitter account. I click connect, and then it just sends me back to the app.

Any idea what is going on?

Code for the action in my ViewController

```
@IBAction func twitterAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if (TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.hasLoggedInUsers()) {
        // App must have at least one logged-in user to compose a Tweet
        let composer = TWTRComposer()
        tweetComposer(composer: composer)
    } else {
        // Log in, and then check again
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { session, error in
            if session != nil { // Log in succeeded
                let composer = TWTRComposer()
                self.tweetComposer(composer: composer)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Twitter Accounts Available", message: "You must log in before presenting a composer.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

func tweetComposer(composer: TWTRComposer){
    let composer = TWTRComposer()
    composer.setText("Trying to get this to work...")
    composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { (result) in
        if (result == .done) {
            print("Successfully composed Tweet")
        } else {
            print("Cancelled composing")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below in your AppDelegate and it should work to handle the twitter composer with your code above

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options:  
[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

  TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

  return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, now I get an error after authorizing... Redirecting you back to the application. This may take a few moments. In Xcode the error is on "composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { (result) in" and the error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrappin in Optional value" any ideas?

Comment: I would use `composer.show(from: self)` since it's possbile that you don't have a navigationController